# Laggy transition in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making a page in HTML, and I am using Javascript for transition:

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar" onmouseover="expand()" onmouseout="collapse()">
```

Javascript:

```
function expand() {
    document.getElementById("main-container").style.marginLeft= "160px";
    document.getElementById("main-container").style.transition = "all 0.2s";
}

function collapse() {
    document.getElementById("main-container").style.marginLeft= "60px";
    document.getElementById("main-container").style.transition = "all 0.2s";
}
```

When running these, they are not smooth, they seems a bit laggy. How can I make them more smooth?

Comment: Margins are animated pixel by pixel: there is no subpixel values possible. Using `translateX()` might be a better idea, which has the advantage of the possibility to offload the element's rendering to the GPU.

Answer (score 2):

try adding animation to elements using classes.

```
<div id="sidebar" onmouseover="expand()" onmouseout="collapse()">
```

```
#sidebar {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

#sidebar.expanded {
    transform: translateX(160px);
}
```

```
function expand() {
document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.add("expanded");
}

function collapse() {
document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.remove("expanded");

}
```

However, if you are trying to create a sidebar, this approach might not be in the correct direction. If you want it to happen on hover, you can try it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lsrawat/3qh1eptw/17/)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `HTML` code, please look at the updated question.

Comment: Edited the answer according to your updated HTML and added a link to the fiddle.